# Gamma spectroscopy - Table of radioactive isotopes with gamma energy search

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, neutrons, gamma-rays

For anyone doing gamma spectroscopy by hand, the task is considerably eased by tables like this:

http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/toi/

Where not only can you search for particular nuclides, but you can search specific energy levels. That's useful to check particular gamma lines on a gamma spectrum against candidate isotopes.

The linked database is, however, not up to date. It also doesn't list any gammas emitted during neutron capture, for example. It also doesn't include what seem to be recently discovered decays, one example being the beta-delayed neutron emission of Co-71 at 1260 KeV. Information on this decay can be found here:

http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/ensdf/xundl.jsp

However, whilst this database is continuously updated, there appears to be no way to search for specific energy levels to check gamma lines which one has on a spectrum against candidate isotopes.

I ask where, if it's not the first link given above, is the most up to date nuclear database with an energy level search function? Or alternatively, a similar database which contains the information for gammas emitted by neutron capture?

Comment: BTW, I should perhaps say that I have done some Germanium spectroscopy before, but I haven't jumped in at full strength because I'm not at all comfortable that I know everything you should know to interpret the spectra you get from the things quickly and easily. I had the advantage of using a couple of very low background machines, but I don't know if you are in the same position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/indx_adopted.jsp

Appears to be the answer I was looking for, if anyone else is interested.

Comment: You're encouraged to mark your own answer as "accepted" to indicate that your problem is solved.

Comment: Helpful links in both answer and question! fyi I've asked [Has a nuclear “neutron halo” been measured directly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/365389/83380)